# VMWare WSX installation issue

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am not able to install VMware WSX in Lubuntu/Ubuntu.
It is extracting the bundlebut not installing it.

[image: Click here to see the image]

Kindly help.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: From where did you get the installation bundle? The [official installation instructions](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2033641) say that you should run `sudo sh VMware-WSX-XXXXXXX.bundle` ("[w]here `XXXXXXX` is the version and build numbers.") and "Follow the prompts and complete the installation." Could you please try that instead?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded official version only. I think "sudo ./.bundle" works same as "sudo sh .bundle" as i have given execution permission to tht file.

Comment: I am not getting prompt that is the problem.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo service vmware-wsx-server start`? If it appears successful, can you access the web server at http://localhost:8888/?

Comment: I am not able to start the service because it is not installed at all. If I press tab after "vmware-", I am not able to see the wsx.

Comment: Can anybody help here?

Comment: Hi @DavidFoerster will you pls help me further?

Answer (score 0):

To install WSX in Linux:

First get the latest version of WSX from [vmware](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?productId=293&downloadGroup=WKST-901-WSX) , then

> Log in to the host using the account that you use to run Workstation.
>   Change to root. For example, run the command: su root
>
> Note: The command that you use depends on your Linux distribution and
>   configuration.
>
> Change to the directory that contains the WSX installer .bundle file.
>   Run the installer from the host system. For example, run this command:

```
sh VMware-WSX-XXXXXXX.bundle
```

Where XXXXXXX is the version and build numbers.

Follow the prompts and complete the installation.

Execute the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware-wsx-server status
```

If it is running then, using a browser, go to: **`http://localhost:8888/`**, there you need to input your system username and password. Afterwards you need to add ESXI server address to access your virtual machines.